# Back button is not working in the browser if multipage is done in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on jQuery. I want to display 2 divs in a same page but only one div has to get displayed when its link is clicked. and is there any condition to make the second div hidden and displaying the first div and when the link for the second div is clicked from the first page the page must load with the second div. 
  I have achieved it through this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
     $("#login").hide();
     $("#loginp").click(function(event){
        $("#login").show();
        $(".container").hide();      
        event.preventDefault();
     });
     });  
   </script>
```

but when i use the above code: back button in the browser fail to work. Please help or suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: You have  a missing `});` closing tag of `doc ready` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing closing tag for `doc ready` handler:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
         $("#login").hide();
         $("#loginp").click(function(event){
            $("#login").show();
            $(".container").hide();      
            event.preventDefault();
         });
      }); //<-----------this one try putting it.
   </script>
```

Comment: it worked. but now the div is getting opened in the new tab. not in the same window

Answer (score 1):

Use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) function for this like,

```
$(function() {
    $("#login").hide();
    $("#loginp").click(function(event){
       $("#login, .container").toggle();      
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: it worked. but now the div is getting opened in the new tab. not in the same window

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="login">
<div class="cont1">

<div id="logincontainer">
<form>
<label> Uname:
<input type="text" name="uname">
</label>
<label> Password:
<input type="password" name="pwd">
</label>
<div class="buttons1">
<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
Submit
</button>
<button type="reset"  id="reset" value="Reset"  class="btn">
Clear All
</button>
</div>
<div>
<div class="rememberme"> 
<label class="checkbox">
<input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="remember" type="checkbox"/>
Remember me </label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

Comment: `Id` having `loginp` is your `anchor tag`?

Comment: yes its <div id="container"> <a href="#login" id="loginp">login</a> </div>